# How to remove `href` attribute from link with Svelte? Should this be enough?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Am I wrong or this should remove `href` attribute from the `a` tag?

```html
<a href={false}></a>
```

It doesn't ("svelte": "3.44.2").

Comment: You chose a later answer as the correct answer while its exactly the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#Attributes_and_props) say

> **Boolean attributes** are included on the element if their value is *truthy* and excluded if it's *falsy*.
> **All other attributes** are included unless their value is *nullish* (null or undefined).

`href=` is no boolean attribute, so `false` doesn't work, use `null/undefined` instead

```html
<a href={null}>linkText</a>
<a href={undefined} >linkText</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `null` and it will deactivate the hyperlink and won't go anywhere.
Or you can add `on:click|preventDefault` to the anchor.

```
<a href={null} on:click|preventDefault>link</a>
```